# Loading a large list of sentences into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, list

I have a large list of phrases / quotes / sentences in a text file. Mixed alphanumeric text, it hasn't been screened for `"`'s or `'`'s.

Is there an easy way to throw this into a table?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) mysql command.